# Python - tcp sockets, creating a catch all function to receive data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a function that can be reused to receive any amount of tcp data reliably.

*Note, this assumes there is already a connection established - where `conn` is my connected socket.*

So far I have the following:

```
import socket

def recv_tcp_data(conn, byte_size):
    chunks = []
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(byte_size)
        if data:
            chunks.append(data)
        else:
            break
    return chunks as result
```

The problem with the above code is that I don't want to return a list of the data that has been received. I want to return it all as one encoded string regardless of the number of buffers, but I can't figure out how to concatenate the `chunks` list of encoded strings together.

For instance I want to be able to run `.decode("utf-8")` on the output of the function directly, without having to manipulate the function output outside of the function.

EDIT: To clarify - I'm trying to create a function to receive buffer(s) of encoded data and then return those buffer(s) as one encoded `result` which can be decoded with `result.decode("utf-8")` outside of the function.

EDIT2: More clarification - **I am basically looking for a `.join()` that works on a list of bytes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use `b"".join(list_name)` to join a list of bytes together

Answer (score 0):

**This would work `b''.join(chunks)`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 1234

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr


def recv_tcp_data(conn, byte_size):
    chunks = []
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(byte_size)
        if data:
            chunks.append(data)
        else:
            break
    return b''.join(chunks)


print recv_tcp_data(conn, 20)
conn.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. I know how to send and receive. I'm trying to create a **function** to **receive** multiple buffers of data and **return** them as one variable that can be decoded. I am not looking to send any data in this function.

Comment: if .join() doesn't answer to your request would you clarify exactly what you need so I can help .

Comment: .join() is exactly what I need. The only problem is that it doesn't work on byte strings so it won't work in this instance

Comment: I need an equivalent to join the encoded strings together